# How Does: "(a = b) != c" work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was looking through jQuery code `$.extend()`

I found this:

```
    if ( (options = arguments[ i ]) != null ) {
        // Extend the base object
```

I was wondering what would happen if we move `options = arguments[i]` out of parenthesis?

Comment: it would assign the result of the `arguments[ i ] != null` comparison to `options`, which you'd discover with a little testing.

Comment: The `(options = arguments[ i ])` evaluates to the new `options` value, so it checks if its `!=` from `null`.

Comment: All you have to do is type it into your console to find out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 a = b!= c
```

will work like,

```
 a = (b != c)
```

since  `=` operator has least precedence in all the operators.

e.g.

```
 b = 5 
 c = 10 

 a = b != c
>>> false
>>> a will have false value here
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is the precedence chart and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WN7pT/1)

In case of `(options = arguments[ i ]) != null`, `options` will be assigned a value of `argument[ i ]` and then compared with `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`a = b` assigns `b` to `a` and returns `b`. Thus, `(a = b) != c` will assign `b` to `a` and then check `b != c`. The parentheses are because otherwise, `!=` will be evaluated before `=` due to the operator precedence (comparison is evaluated before assignment - [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

Comment: that's what i am asking, what will happen when != is evaluated before =, will it return a boolean value ?

Comment: Why are you asking us, when you can just try it yourself in the browser's console? `b=1;c=2;a=b!=c;`

Answer (score 0):

Assignment has less precedence than equality which means

```
arguments[i] != null
```

would be processed before

```
options = arguments[i]
```

Given a different result than what is desired.
To understand it a little better check here and read about operator precedence

Comment: Also yes, the result of (b != null) will return a 1 or a 0 depending on whether it's true or false.